# How to remove Objects from List(Of myClass) by Object Value?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

Is there a simple way to remove Objects from a List by using a specified value?
I add 2 persons to a List, how can now I remove a person by a name without using any Loops? (if possible)

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Persons As New List(Of Person)
    Private Sub Test()
        Persons.Add(New Person With {.Name = "Jamie", .Age = 99})
        Persons.Add(New Person With {.Name = "Adam", .Age = 40})

        'How to remove a person from the list having the name "Jamie" ?
        'Persons.Remove(Name = "Jamie")... ???
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Person
    Public Name As String
    Public Age As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: It's going to be impossible to remove the item without using a loop of some sort. If you want to be able to access an item by name, you should consider moving to a `Dictionary<string, Person>` class, where the `Name` of the object is the key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Persons.RemoveAll(person => person.Name == "Jamie")
```

in VB:

```
Persons.RemoveAll(Function(person) person.Name = "Jamie")
```

(Thanks Heinzi)

Comment: In VB: `Persons.RemoveAll(Function(person) person.Name = "Jamie")`

Comment: yes i changed it to vb.net but it doesnt matter, i speak sharp too ;)

Comment: @qxxx Haahh thanks. I was wondering whether it was time to change my glasses. You've got the lambda in both languages now so pick and choose...

Answer (score 3):

It's just doing so:

```
Persons.Remove(Persons.Single(Function(person) person.Name = "Jamie"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a couple of options.

1. You can override the `.Equals` method for your type and use the `Name` property as the key to determine equivalence.  This is probably not a good idea for a `Person` class as multiple people may have the same name.
2. Persons.RemoveAll(Function(person) person.Name = "Jamie")